# NextJS cors has wrong 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value

Tags: next.js, netlify, swr

I noticed an issue after deploying to Netlify, chrome was blocking my ajax requests to a public Apple api, but it was working for the friends I sent a link to.

Now it's broken in the opposite direction.  It seems like the header is my netlify url rather than localhost in development.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=podcast&term=test&limit=6' 
from origin 
'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header has a value 'https://effulgent-dingus-192e6.netlify.app' 
that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, 
or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' 
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How can I make sure the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't cached (or fix whatever the problem is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that NextJS was running the API call on the server side as well as the intended client side.  I wrapped the call in a check to see if `window !== undefined` to do the call client side only.  I think this has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent caching, include a `Vary: Origin` header in the response.

> CORS and caching
>
> Suppose the server sends a response with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin value with an explicit origin (rather than the "*" wildcard). In that case, the response should also include a Vary response header with the value Origin — to indicate to browsers that server responses can differ based on the value of the Origin request header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#cors_and_caching

Comment: In this case though I'm requesting data from Apple's public API, so I don't have the ability to edit the response.